# How to reach nested struct elements

Tags: json, go, struct

I have struct like this. And I want to parse my Json to this struct. But I can not reach nested structs.

I was expecting to reach sub structs for like, but I can not:

```golang
func main() {
    str := `[{
        "ApplicationDefaults":  {
            "ApplicationPoolName": "DefaultAppPool",
                ....
    }]`

    mdl := foo(str)

    // mdl.ApplicationDefaults ?? I can't reach like this. There are only a few functions like: append!, last! , print!, range!, reverse!, sort!, var!
}
```

Any one help?

My struct:

```golang
package model

type SitesDetails []struct {
    ApplicationDefaults struct {
        ApplicationPoolName string      `json:"ApplicationPoolName"`
        EnabledProtocols    string      `json:"EnabledProtocols"`
        Attributes          string      `json:"Attributes"`
        ChildElements       string      `json:"ChildElements"`
        ElementTagName      string      `json:"ElementTagName"`
        IsLocallyStored     bool        `json:"IsLocallyStored"`
        Methods             interface{} `json:"Methods"`
        RawAttributes       string      `json:"RawAttributes"`
        Schema              string      `json:"Schema"`
    } `json:"ApplicationDefaults"`
    Applications []string `json:"Applications"`
    Bindings     []string `json:"Bindings"`
    ID           int      `json:"Id"`
    Limits       struct {
        ConnectionTimeout string      `json:"ConnectionTimeout"`
        MaxBandwidth      int64       `json:"MaxBandwidth"`
        MaxConnections    int64       `json:"MaxConnections"`
        MaxURLSegments    int         `json:"MaxUrlSegments"`
        Attributes        string      `json:"Attributes"`
        ChildElements     string      `json:"ChildElements"`
        ElementTagName    string      `json:"ElementTagName"`
        IsLocallyStored   bool        `json:"IsLocallyStored"`
        Methods           interface{} `json:"Methods"`
        RawAttributes     string      `json:"RawAttributes"`
        Schema            string      `json:"Schema"`
    } `json:"Limits"`
}
```

This is the code that I use for parse json to my struct :

```golang
func foo(resp string) model.SitesDetails {
    data := []byte(resp)

    var m model.SitesDetails
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return m
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check the format of your question and try to fix the display of Go code block first.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to learn it. Sorry for that. Can you check it again? @ChangQian

Comment: `type SitesDetails []struct {...}` declares a _slice_ of structs, meaning a type that can hold 0 or more `struct{...}` instances. Therefore doing `model.ApplicationDefaults` is simply not allowed because it's unclear on which instance in the slice you want to access the field. So you MUST specify the instance by using an index expression. If it's the first instance you want then use 0, if it's the second then use 1, e.g. `model[0].ApplicationDefaults`.

Comment: A quick hint on code formatting: Use code fences (three backticks) on either side of the code rather than indentation, it's way easier to properly format the code that way. Bonus points if you add the language name after the opening fence (```go), so you get syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually, I didn't use it as a variable name, but I gave it this name when I was trying to explain my problem here. I updated it when I realized this, but you have already replied. By the way, which IDE are you using, GoLand?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA with the Go plugin, which is pretty much the same as GoLand, yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're unmarshalling into a ***slice*** here (as your `SitesDetails` type is a `[]struct` and your json starts with an array), so you should be able to access your details via

```golang
poolName := model[0].ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName
```

This also explains why your IDE only suggests actions that can be applied to slices, such as appending (which I guess would insert the proper code to append to your slice).

By the way, you really shouldn't call your variable `model`, as that's the name your apparently using for your package as well (you're using `model.SitesDetails`), so your variable name would shadow the package at that point - this could cause great confusion down the line and any decent IDE should warn you about that.